# ideal diode circuit question

Tags: diodes, ideal

Can some one show me an example about how to do these 2 simple questions..

[image]

[image]

(a.)As Vo=0.7V, want [Is]
(b.)As Vo=1.5V, want [R2]

Comment: Meh, you don't provide anything what you tried yourself or where exactly you are stuck - you won't get much love here for this question. Hint for 1.a: Calculate the current id with the help of the resistor R1 and v0.

Comment: Unclear: there's no information about where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You're close!

Vd = Vo

I = Id

Vo = Vdd - I * R

And your equation for diode current.

Let me know if you need help with the algebra, arithmetic, or taking your midterm.

Comment: thank you! From the hint I have get to the part that Id=2[mA], but Now I am really stuck with the diode current equation, the {exp(Vd/nVt)} part just give a very large number around (2.4x10^9) which make me wonder if I was doing it right. Sorry for asking this but I could not find good sample questions from anywhere so...